# Rails_Javascript loads only if I pass by index home page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rating-system

I am facing a javascript issue on Rails;
I used [this](https://github.com/RyanHemrick/Book-Review) web app in order to publish a book rating system

I've noticed that when I go to my homepage (index), then I click on the book that I want to rate (, the script loads and everything works fine, but when I go directly to the book without passing by the home page, the script of rating will not load

**on application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

**on the head of application.html.erb**

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Can you show your JavaScript?

Comment: Here it is: https://github.com/RyanHemrick/Book-Review/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/jquery.raty.js; Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It may be caused by turbolinks which uses AJAX to view templates to speed things up. But it will cause JavaScripts to not load without a page refresh. You can try removing the turbolinks gem from your gemfile and run bundle install. Alternatively you can wrap the raty javascript with the following. So put the first line at the beginning of your javascript and close your javascript with the last line.

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  ...your jQuery/javascript goes here...
});
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately this didnt solve the issue; Just to precise, even when I refresh, the script will not load, I have to access to the home page, then to the page of rating